# What is the best way to implement cancellable background task in MonoTouch?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.ios

The C# async await feature is not yet available in MonoTouch 6.0. Until then what is the best way to implement an async task in MonoTouch.

The MonoTouch docs recommend Threading from the System.Threading namespace to create responsive UI. But once the background worker thread is going how do I cancel it if it takes a long time? Do I need to implement a timer say for 60 secs and kill the thread when the timer event fires?

Are there better options?

Any help highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how much Mono has of the CLR at this point, but for background tasks, here's my list, [most-recommended first (full details on the rankings can be found on my blog)](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html):

1. `Task`
2. `BackgroundWorker`
3. `Delegate.BeginInvoke`
4. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`
5. `Thread`

For a "cancellation flag", I'd recommend one of these:

1. `CancellationToken` - the gold standard. Use this if it's available.
2. `ManualResetEvent`
3. `volatile bool`

Cancellation is cooperative by nature, so the canceling side sends a cancellation notification, and the receiving side must periodically check it.

Comment: Thank you for the great list. I understand Aborting manually is not ideal but here's the situation. 1. UI Calls Login method on the server on the "background" thread. 2. UI displays hourglass. 3. Login is a blocking call so how do I check for the abort flag set externally? I am reading up on your excellent blogpost and may find an answer in there.

Comment: In that situation, I recommend you do a "logical" cancellation: after you set the cancellation notification, act like it was canceled. When it completes, check for cancellation and if it was canceled then just ignore the result (or log out of you have to). I would not use a thread abort in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Using a thread is a good option. However, it's best not to terminate (abort) the thread from outside directly. Instead, the code that runs in the thread should check for a flag periodically, and if the flag is put to true, then it should return early.

There is an excellent walkthrough and sample on MSDN:

[How to: Create and Terminate Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link. I would have to abort the thread if the background work is take a while to complete.

Comment: @rams When I say 'abort', I mean try not to use Thread.Abort() to do the termination. As per Stephen Cleary's answer, use a volatile bool or a ManualResetEvent to signal to the thread that it should terminate

Comment: In addition to that, you should abort the operation that the thread is executing, for instance by calling `HttpWebRequest.Abort()` - most I/O and networking operations have some kind of an abort method.

Comment: C# async does something similar: it aborts the currently running IO/network operation by calling its `Abort()` method and the background thread must actively support cancellation by periodically checks some flag.  It never calls `Thread.Abort()` to hard-abort.